# Pandas - combine two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 columns, which we'll call `x` and `y`. I want to create a new column called `xy`:

```
x    y    xy
1         1
2         2

     4    4
     8    8
```

*There shouldn't be any conflicting values, but if there are, y takes precedence. If it makes the solution easier, you can assume that `x` will always be `NaN` where `y` has a value.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it could be quite simple if your example is accurate

```
df.fillna(0)      #if the blanks are nan will need this line first
df['xy']=df['x']+df['y']
```

Comment: Or `df.x.combine_first(df.y)`

Comment: Or that will work too. Pandas is like skinning a cat

Comment: Awesome, this worked. However, looking at the combine_first example, shouldn't it be df.y.combine_first(df.x) if you want y to take precedence (in case they both have values)?

Comment: If the blank are blank , by using your code I received `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
`

Comment: @JesusMonroe yes... put it in order of precedence... it was just an example :)

Answer (score 3):

Notice your column type right now is string not numeric anymore

```
df = df.apply(lambda x : pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))

df['xy'] = df.sum(1)
```

More

```
df['xy'] =df[['x','y']].astype(str).apply(''.join,1)

#df[['x','y']].astype(str).apply(''.join,1)
Out[655]: 
0    1.0
1    2.0
2       
3    4.0
4    8.0
dtype: object
```

Comment: You don't need the `lambda` here: you can write it as `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use NumPy:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'y': [np.nan, np.nan, 4, 8]})

arr = df.values
df['xy'] = arr[~np.isnan(arr)].astype(int)

print(df)

     x    y  xy
0  1.0  NaN   1
1  2.0  NaN   2
2  NaN  4.0   4
3  NaN  8.0   8
```