# How do I join 2 columns on Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am working with two data frames that I joined using

```
 df = pd.concat([hc,nh], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

and now need to combine a few like-columns. For example:

```
Country   Country_ID  
1         
2         
             3
             4
```

How do I make it so it'd look like this:

```
Country
1
2
3
4
```

*I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51635290/pandas-combine-two-columns) that is a similar question to mine, but the answer there didn't work for me...*

Comment: Do not include your code/data as images. Copy/paste the text in the question.

Comment: you can remane the column *as* you merge in the dataframe.

Comment: Are `"Country"` and `"Country ID"` identical?  Why not just drop one of them?

Comment: @DavidErickson May you please show me an example of how I can do that?

Comment: @JAV They are not identical, so it would be like x has rows 1-5 and y has rows 6-10. And the column xy (or x?) that I want both to merge to would have rows 1-10. Sorry, this is my first time posting a question so I'm not familiar with the syntax to show code blocks properly...

Comment: @mymojoh please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples . The answers in there should help you understand how you can improve your question so that can someone can answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country': [1,2, None, None],
    'Country ID': [None, None, 3, 4]
})
```

Data from one column can be assigned to another one using [np.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Country'] = np.where(df['Country'].isna(), df['Country ID'], df['Country'])
```